# Is there any way to re-enable YouTube's speed-up controls?

Tags: youtube

Other than downloading the video, is there any way to re-enable YouTube's speed-up controls, which allowed playback w/ 1.5x, 2x, 4x the original speed?

(This was the only way I could watch lectures and vlogs; they are essential for those videos.)

Answer (score 1):

The optional HTML5 version of youtube has it: http://www.youtube.com/html5